# Why rpm-Uvh command is removing the other version’s of my jdk package. I want to upgrade only jdk-11 with its latest release

Tags: java-8, java-11, rpm, rpmbuild

When i am upgrading jdk-11.0_18 to jdk-11.0_19 using rpm -Uvh command in playbook. Then why it is deleting the other jdk version i.e jdk-17 and jdk-8. How can i upgrade jdk-11 using rpm command without removing other versions?

I tried soo many things but still want you to give me every possible way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you told rpm to **upgrade** your package. And that means installing a new version and removing the old one. That works for packages like `firefox`, `postgresql`, etc... But does not work for your `jdk` where you want to have multiple packages.

Most packagers solve it that the version is part of the name of package. E.g., you have

java-17-openjdk.spec:

```
Name: java-17-openjdk
Version: 17.0.7.0.7
```

and

java-11-openjdk.spec:

```
Name: java-11-openjdk
Version: 11.0.18.0.10
```

And rpm consider it as two not related packages and happily keeps them both in the system during upgrades. You just need to be sure that there is no same file to avoid pathname conflicts.

Comment: I want to keep 3 different versions of jdk in the server and i know that we can only use one at a time but we can keep it in the server...   for eg:- jdk11, jdk-8 and jdk-17 are installed on my server and now i want to upgrade only jdk-8 with its latest release without removing jdk-11 and jdk-17. How can i do that? My issue is only with the upgradation of the particular jdk. If i  use rpm -Uvh command to upgrade jdk-8 which is lower version than 11&17 but still it will remove the other 2. Thats the issue….why it is removing other packages.